# Gson and Kotlin serialising the instance of the class causes an InaccessibleObjectException (Unable to make field private)

Tags: kotlin, exception, gson

```
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.Reference.referent accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.ref" to unnamed module @40444e23
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.UnsafeReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(UnsafeReflectionAccessor.java:44) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:159) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:727) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:714) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:649) ~[gson-2.8.9.jar:?]
    at de.carina.pixelsjump.util.arena.Arena.saveArena(Arena.kt:35) ~[PixelsJumpRemastered-1.0.0-all.jar:?]
    at de.carina.pixelsjump.commands.setup.ArenaFinish.execute(ArenaFinish.kt:53) ~[PixelsJumpRemastered-1.0.0-all.jar:?]
    at de.carina.pixelsjump.commands.util.CommandRegister.onCommand(CommandRegister.kt:36) ~[PixelsJumpRemastered-1.0.0-all.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.Reference.referent accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.ref" to unnamed module @40444e23
```

Any good ideas?
Im Using Kotlin as my Language
The thing is, that Im not really able to identify how to fix this specific issue?
Guess its cause Im using Kotlin or so?

my Class that I want to serialise with "Gson"

```
class Arena(val name: String) {
    val checkPoints: MutableList<Location> = mutableListOf()
    var startLocation: Location? = null
     var finishLocation: Location? = null
     var backLocation: Location? = null
    val players = mutableSetOf<Player>()

    @Transient
    private val file: File = File("plugins/PixelsJumpRemastered/arenas/$name.json")
    var single: Boolean = false
    var damage: Boolean = false

    fun saveArena() {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
        var json = gson.toJson(this)
        file.writeText(json)
    }


    fun addCheckpointLocation(location: Location) {
        checkPoints.add(location.block.getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).location.toCenterLocation())
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1875

Answer (score 0):

When Gson has no built-in adapter for a class and you have not registered a custom adapter for that class either, Gson uses reflection to access the fields (including `private` ones) and use them for conversion to JSON.

While this might be fine for your own model classes, you should avoid relying on it for third party classes (such as JDK classes) because it makes you dependent on their internal implementation, which could change at any point.

In this specific case you are relying on Gson's reflection-based serialization for the JDK class `java.lang.ref.Reference`. Recent JDKs prevent you from accessing the internal fields with reflection (see [JEP 403](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403) and older JEPs).

To solve this problem, either write a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for the class, or in case the field is not relevant for the JSON output, you can make it `transient` or specify an [`ExclusionStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html).